# Where are the project settings for Codenameone in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone, intellij-14

I am new to codenameone and I am thinking about moving a large project from our current environment to it. So, I wanted to run a few tests but I already failed by setting up a project, since I do not find the place where to set it up :)

So I used Google and found a Video "HOW DO I - CREATE A BASIC HELLO WORLD APPLICATION & SEND IT TO MY DEVICE USING INTELLIJ/IDEA" and thought "Yeah, exactly what I need!". But when you start the video, one of the first sentences is "We are going to use Eclipse....", so I guess someone has published the wrong video.

Nevertheless, can someone tell me, where I can make the proper project settings (like in the mentioned video on 07:50) in IDEA ?

Answer (score 2):

Type CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S to open the Project Settings dialog box.

You can [read more about it here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guess your answer fits for Windows Systems.

Nevertheless, on OSX you have to go to the preferences and there to "Other Settings" and there you can do all adjustments.

Personally, I hoped that they included the possibility to create multiple apps from one project (like e.g. Adobe AIR) :(

Comment: This is somewhat IDEA specific so we didn't go for the multiple apps per project approach. Its a strategic decision that goes with supporting multiple IDE's simultaneously.